# when I'm trying to get the items inside the Recycle Bin using CSOM, I got the result like nothing in the recycle bin

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom, sharepoint-rest-api

I have tried to get the collection of items inside the Site's RecycleBin.
By Using CSOM

````
```
var web = Site.Web();
var bin = web.RecycleBin;
context.Load(bin);
context.ExecuteQuery();
Console.WriteLine(bin.count);
```
````

for the above code snippet, I got the count is zero('0'). Even though the site's recycle bin contains some file and also the 2nd stage recycle bin contains the files.

Is there any way to get the items inside the Recycle bin or its a bug or I need to include some property before loading it to context.

Comment: Can you provide detailed code or explanation? This can better help everyone understand your problem

Comment: Thanks for the response ChengFeng, I have found the solution. We need to authenticate and create a ClientContext on Site level and need to Load the property "Site.RecycleBin". It contains the Collection of Items of the Recycle Bin (Both Stage 1 and Stage 2).